# Is there any GUI network/bandwidth monitor?

Tags: networking, network-manager

Is there any GUI network/bandwidth analyser which gives network consumptions per process and an overall sum over a large period of time?

I use `nethogs` which is great but it's for command line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Nutty](https://babluboy.github.io/nutty/) is one such graphical network information and monitoring tool that works on Ubuntu. But it *is not maintained anymore since 2017* .

Nutty is available as a PPA for Ubuntu (16.04 upwards) and other Ubuntu based systems. Open Terminal and run the following comands for installation

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:bablu-boy/nutty
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install com.github.babluboy.nutty
```

In case of issues related to missing libgranite package, add the Elementary PPA as shown below and re-try. The Elementary PPA can be removed after Nutty is installed.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install com.github.babluboy.nutty
```

Comment: Is it paid or fully free?

Comment: It's open source and fully free.

Comment: type 'snap install nutty' instead

Comment: That snap hasn't been updated since 2017 and at least as of today does not work on 20.04, in case someone comes across this like I did through a search engine.

The debs or installing from source should still work (I have not tried those routes yet) but the snap doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

open your "ubuntu software" app and search for **netspeed**, install this extension.

It's free software that shows your downloading and uploading status.